# @ngdoc not recognised when creating a doc for an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

When I attempt to create a doc for a directive a squiggly line appears under @ngdoc and when the mouse is over it the information says there is a typo:

[image]

Why isn't @ngdoc recognised as a valid element in the doc? In the video for the **AnjularJS Workflow in Webstorm** it seems to be valid http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/ (time 3:04)

Comment: 1) Do you have AngularJS plugin installed? 2) Maybe they have added it manually to the dictionary before recording that video?

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, the AngularJS plugin is installed. They may have added it manually to the dictionary but my guess is that they didn't. Do you know how to view the predefined doc elements?

Comment: I'm not JS guy .. but try Ctrl+Space after entering `@` (or whatever you may have there on Mac for "Code | Completion | Basic") -- it should list all supported/applicable-here tags.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. It is not there in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `@ngdoc` is somehow supported - information provided in this annotation is used for type hinting in Angular projects
2. If you think that this tag should be added to JSDoc tags completion, please feel free to file a request to youtrack, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB
3. unfortunately spelling errors are often shown even for supported tags, etc. Please see [WI-4762](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4762)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your first point. Also, could you tell me why it does not appear as a spelling error in the video?

Comment: What is unclear? the IDE uses the annotations to get more information about directives, etc. As for spelling errors not shown, you can easily get rid of them. Either add 'ngdoc' to a dictionary (Alt+Enter, Save 'ngdoc' to dictionary), or disable spell checking completely (Settings/Inspections/Spelling/Typo)